# Typescript - How do I import extension method from library

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, extension-methods

I've created a library with has the following extension method:

```
type PromiseFunc = (item: any) => Promise<any>;

interface Array<T> {
  mapParallel(action: PromiseFunc): Promise<Array<any>>;
}

Array.prototype.mapParallel = async function (this: Array<any>, asyncAction) {
  return await Promise.all(this.map(element => asyncAction(element)));
};
```

I want to be able to use this function in my other projects. what do I need to write in my index.js to export the above function? and how do I import it so typescript will recognize it?

Comment: Use an ECMAScript Module side-effecting import. `import 'module';`. note there is no `from` because it means just for side-effects and no exports are consumed.

Comment: It is automatically included in some scenarios without needing explicit import.

https://github.com/ca0v/typescriptlab/blob/v1.0.1/ext/Array.ts is available from https://github.com/ca0v/typescriptlab/blob/v1.0.1/src/index.ts without import.  See "foobar" is defined in https://github.com/ca0v/typescriptlab/blob/v1.0.1/dist/index.js.